# IndexError: pop from empty stack (python)

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to import the excel file with the following code and the size file is about 71 Mb and when runing the code, it shows "IndexError: pop from empty stack". Thus, kindly help me with this.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('F:/Test PCA/Week-7-MachineLearning/weather.xlsx',
                    sheetname='Sheet1', header=0)
```

Data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zyrry53li55hvha/weather.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Please include the name of the library you are using to read the excel file.

Comment: Thank Abhishek. I already include, but it doesn't work. could you help me with this?

Comment: [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the latest pandas and xlrd this works fine to read the "weather.xlsx" file you provided:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('weather.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Can you try running:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
pip install --upgrade xlrd
```

To ensure you have the latest version of the modules for reading the file?

Comment: I copy and paste your code, but it doesn't work. It shows syntax error. 

File "<module2>", line 1
    pip install --upgrade pandas
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

i tried with same code provided by you with below versions of pandas and xlrd and it is working fine just changed sheetname argument to sheet_name

```
pandas==0.22.0
xlrd==1.1.0
df=pd.read_excel('weather.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1',header=0)
```